# Shopify + CartJS updating total price with JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, shopify

I'm trying to update some data with AJAX on my Shopify theme, I'm also using the CartJS plugin. I have the counter working find but when I come to update the price it doesn't format correctly. It does add all the correct numbers but misses out any currency symbol or decimal point.

Here's the code snippet:

```
<div id="mini-cart">
    <h2>Basket Updated <span class="btn-close">x</span></h2>
    <p><strong class="item-count">{{ cart.item_count }}</strong> item(s). Costing <strong class="total-price">{{ cart.total_price | money }}</strong></p>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).on('cart.requestComplete', function(event, cart) {

        $('.item-count').html(cart.item_count);
        $('.total-price').html(cart.total_price);
    });
</script>
```

I think it has something to do with `{{ cart.total_price | money }}` but whenever I add the `| money` bit into the JS the whole thing breaks. Is there a way to format that in the script?

Thanks!

Comment: Normally with this plugin you could declare a class (like `.item-count`) and then add the class around what you want to update. Works fine for the counter, just can't get it working on the price. That `{{ cart.total_price | money }}` is the price code from the Shopify cart page so it should be correct.

Answer (score 1):

You should be sure to load also the `option_selection.js` library in your `theme.liquid` here is the string to add:

```
{{ 'option_selection.js' | shopify_asset_url | script_tag }}
```

Ref. https://cartjs.org/pages/guide#getting-started-setup

Comment: Thanks, I'll bring this up with the devs tomorrow and see if it's any good and update you all being well! :)

Comment: Cool, any news? :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add use data-cart-view to display values and products from your cart. Simply use:

```
<span data-cart-view>
Costing <strong class="total-price">{{ cart.total_price | money }}</strong>
</span>
```